# Custom font displaying differently in two different themes

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

So this one has had my scratching my head for over an hour now. I am designing a Wordpress theme for a client of mine. I originally decided to customize the Toolbox theme, which I did for a week or so. I spent so much time rewriting their theme, I figured it would be better if I just wrote it from scratch. So I did that. I copied over all of the font files that I had and started to work on my header. Now for some reason the spacing is messed up. Originally it looks like:

[image: this]

Which I think is pretty readable. I have the font-size set at 70px on that image. So I copied the SAME exact css properties over to my new file on my new theme. Then I copied the same exact code within my header. When I saved and refreshed my browser, the font was there, but the spaces between the words were really small, and the font was much larger.

Here is was it looked like when I was done:

[image: Here]

Looking at it, I think the words are way too close together. It worked fine before and I can't find what would have caused the change. They both have the bootstrap css file attached and the same custom CSS file. I tried adding the original toolbox CSS file to see if it was something in there that caused the change but nothing.

I would really appreciate the help. I've never had this problem before. I'm using Chrome, but the same thing happens in Safari as well. The font I'm using is Bebas Neue from font squirrel

Thank you! If I left any information out, just ask :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To get started, inspect both elements using your browser's element inspector and see what CSS rules apply to them. There may be a global `letter-spacing` setting set in the second location (or the first)

Comment: I've looked through all of the rules that apply to both texts. I tried to use the letter-spacing, it changed the text, but it didn't do anything for the spaces in the font or the size different between browsers. The one that's correct is set for size 70px font. While I had to set the other one to 55px for a similar size.

Comment: Do you have a live link to look at?

Comment: I'm actually using a localhost to work on the design. I know it makes it difficult, I just don't have a online site to test with at the moment.

Comment: I still think this could be a global setting somewhere - perhaps something like `font-size: 150%`, or perhaps a zoom setting in the browser?

Comment: I thought that too, but I really can't find anything. Plus I don't think that would affect the spacing between words. I've really looked over everything I can. I'm going to start over, completely rewrite all of the CSS and see what I can do from there.

Comment: looking at the fonts closely, they aren't the same at all. Look at the R for example. It's a different font altogether.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't notice that before. I copied over the font files and made sure all of the stylesheets were linked correctly. Or I thought I did. After reworking it for a while I just refreshed and it's back to normal! Thank you for your help!